# iOS background uploading of images

Tags: ios, http, background-process, afnetworking

I have made an application which uploads a bunch of photos to a web server. It does so by repeated html calls, using multiple AFNetworking's AFHTPRequestOperation inside an operation queue. Right now, of the user exits the application, the queue stops. However, I want to continue the uploading queue until it's done, and then let the application go to sleep like it normally does.

I know that iOS provides a background expiration handler using "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler" . I also know that AFURLConnectionOperation which is superclass of every HTTP operation class in AFNetworking can use that using

```
- (void)setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void (^)(void))handler
```

But is there any way of making this work with an operation queue? Will setting the expiration handler of each operation do the job properly if I want to upload, let's say 10 photos?

I would appreciate any comments on background tasks with AFNetworking, or if anyone has experienced the same problem as me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an app goes to background, the OS will decide whether or not to completely stop your app or give it some time to complete what it's doing. In case it wants your app to stop, the expiration handler is called. If that's happening you should suspend all your tasks as fast as possible and prepare for a complete kill of the app, because that is what will happen a very short time after (5 seconds max). Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20).